# Ajax Chat front end supporting IRC backend

Tags: ajax, chat, irc

I am looking for an **ajax web chat solution** that **supports IRC back end**. Basically I have my own IRC server. I want to configure an ajax web chat solution to connect to it. I found tons of ajax web chat solution in Google. But none (except **mibbit** which is not opensource) matches my criteria.

Do you know of any? If not found I might write one. But I dont want to go to that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Atheme's Iris](http://www.atheme.net/iris.html) that might fit the bill.

Comment: Great solution. Let me check it.

Comment: This is good. and allows UI customization. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, I do not know of any. However, I can explain how to implement one: you should be able to take *any* frontend to any web-based chat client (for example's sake, let's say PHP backend/Javascript frontend), keep it intact, and then modify the backend to suit your needs. If you can find a well-written chat script, you should be able to implement the interfaces it already uses for its own custom chat implementation, which might consist of something like:

```
interface Chattable
{
  function connectToChatDaemon($ip, $channel);
  function listen();
  function proxyMessageFromClient($message);
  function sendMessageToClient($blah);
}
```

and then re-implement it for IRC! Good luck (:

Comment: I didn't find any script that actually talks to any deamon. Most are keeps the chat messges. Do you know a dameon based solution?

Comment: No, I do not. Even if they keep the chat messages, the principle is the same.